# RegExp string.match doesn't work

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my code but for some reason it doesn't work anybody got a clue?

```
var val="My1name"
var exp = new RegExp("((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,20})"); 
if(!val.match(exp)){      
   alert("No match")
} else {
   alert("Match")
}
```

Comment: Use the literal grammar for creating regular expressions if they're going to be constant. `var exp = /((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,20})/`

Comment: am not i am is right, you've got to escape some characters. But if you don't really need the new RegExp(...) way why not use /.../ instead?

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the escape characters when building from a string...

```
var exp = new RegExp("((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,20})"); 
 //-------------------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this?

```
var val = "My1name";
var exp = /((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,20})/; 
if(!val.match(exp)){      
   alert("No match");
} else {
   alert("Match");
}
```